# Contact Form Sending message even if captcha not correct

Tags: javascript, html, forms, phpmailer, captcha

I am trying to implement a Contact from with custom Captcha using PHPmailer. The contact form works fine. The PHPmailer works fine as well. To avoid a lot of spam letters, I decided to implement custom Captcha, the problem is that the emails go anyway captcha is correct or incorrect.

```
<h4 class="sent-notification"></h4>
<form id="myForm">
  <p>
    <label>Name<span style="color:#ff0000; margin-left:5px;">*</span></label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Company<span style="color:#ff0000; margin-left:5px;">*</span></label>
    <input id="subject" type="text" name="company" required>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Email<span style="color:#ff0000; margin-left:5px;">*</span></label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
  </p>
  <p class="full">
    <label>Message<span style="color:#ff0000; margin-left:5px;">*</span></label>
    <textarea id="body" name="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
  </p>
  <div class="contain">
    <input type="text" id="capt" readonly="readonly">
    <div id="refresh"> <img src="assets/img/icons/refresh.png" alt="refresh" width="50px" onclick="cap()"></div>

    <input type="text" id="textinput" placeholder="Refresh to type Captcha" required>
    <button onclick="validcap()">Check</button>
  </div>
    <p>
      <button class="full" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send An Email">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Script for PHPmailer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function sendEmail() {
          var name = $("#name");
          var email = $("#email");
          var subject = $("#subject");
          var body = $("#body");
          var textinput = $("#textinput");

          if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject) && isNotEmpty(body) && isNotEmpty(textinput)) {
              $.ajax({
                 url: 'sendEmail.php',
                 method: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: {
                     name: name.val(),
                     email: email.val(),
                     subject: subject.val(),
                     body: body.val(),
                     textinput: textinput.val()
                 }, success: function (response) {
                      $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                      $('.sent-notification').text("Message Sent Successfully");
                 }
              });
          }
      }

      function isNotEmpty(caller) {
          if (caller.val() == "") {
              caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
              return false;
          } else
              caller.css('border', '');

          return true;
      }
  </script>
```

Script for Captcha

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function cap() {

        var alpha=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V'
                   ,'W','X','Y','Z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',
                   'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

        var a=alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*62)];
        var b=alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*62)];
        var c=alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*62)];
        var d=alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*62)];
        var e=alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*62)];
        var f=alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*62)];

        var sum=a + b + c + d + e + f;

        document.getElementById("capt").value=sum;
    }

    function validcap() {
        var string1 = document.getElementById('capt').value;
        var string2 = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
        if (string1 == string2){
            alert("Form is validated Succesfully");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Please enter a valid captcha");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I can see you're not calling your captcha validation function before making the email request, i.e. there are no calls to `validcap()` in your `sendEmail()` function, so it's not doing any validation before sending. Also there's no indication that you're also applying any of this validation on the server side as well, which means you're still vulnerable to spambots which can bypass javascript.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to correctly implement a captcha code into existing contact form or even a simple example of a form with captcha?